# How to fix LazyInitializationException with GWT?

Tags: hibernate, gwt, lazy-initialization

I have:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

This is my service:

```
@Service("empService")
public class EmpServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements EmpService {
    @Autowired
    EmpHome empHome;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Emp findById(short id) {
        return empHome.findById(id);
    }
```

Im trying to use my service in gwt:

```
EmpServiceAsync empServiceAsync = GWT.create(EmpService.class);
        AsyncCallback<Emp> callback = new AsyncCallback<Emp>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                Info.display("Failure", "что-то пошло не так");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Emp result) {
                Info.display("Succes", result.getEname());
            }
        };

        empServiceAsync.findById((short) 7844, callback);
```

Comment: You should provide more details about the `Emp` Object. Does it have relations to other entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly discourage using Hibernate mapped object `Emp` in GWT client side directly.
Your Hibernate session will only be available inside `findById` as it is marked `@Transactional`, however, GWT will need to traverse the entire `Emp` object to serialize it for client. That will obviously happen outside `findById` hence you will get `LazyInitializationException` if `Emp` contains any properties that require lazy loading (for example, association lists).

The solution is to use intermediate data transfer object, for example `EmpDTO` and convert `Emp` to `EmpDTO` inside your service transactional block.

Comment: Thank you! Im find this manual http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html and Dozer fix my error

Comment: There is nothing contradictory in the article. Dozer just generates DTO for you, which is essentially what I suggested. Not sure why you unaccepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got around this issue by creating a CustomFieldSerializer for my domain objects.

Take a look at this file: https://github.com/dartmanx/mapmaker/blob/0.5.2/src/main/java/org/jason/mapmaker/shared/model/FeaturesMetadata_CustomFieldSerializer.java

I've commented out the relevant lines because I ended up not needing it, but here's the code:

```
public static void serialize(SerializationStreamWriter writer, FeaturesMetadata instance) throws SerializationException {        
    writer.writeInt(instance.getId());
    writer.writeString(instance.getState());
    writer.writeString(instance.getStateAbbr());
    writer.writeString(instance.getUsgsDate());
    writer.writeString(instance.getFilename());
    writer.writeString(instance.getStateGeoId());
    writer.writeString(instance.getCurrentStatus());
    if (instance.getFeatureList().size() == 0) {
        writer.writeObject(new ArrayList<Feature>());
    } else {
        writer.writeObject(new ArrayList<Feature>(instance.getFeatureList()));
    }
}
```

The final line takes the takes an argument of the instance object's getFeatureList(), which is actually a Hibernate PersistentBag, and writes out an actual ArrayList with the contents of said PersistentBag.